# Cardinality Confusion - Should state field (50 states) index have cardinality of 50?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working with a database with names and addresses.  One of the fields is 'state_abbreviation'.

My data has 50 states, plus DC, so a total of 51 unique state abbreviations.  I know there are only those because this query has only 51 results:

```
Select state_abbreviation from table group by state_abbreviation
```

I created an index on this field, name: "index_state", type: "index", the field is a varchar(5).

When I look at the structure of the table, the index looks strange to me because it says:
Type: BTREE
Unique: No
Packed: No
Cardinality: 108
Collation: A

Shouldn't the cardinality be 51?

Comment: Is this a real query? From which table are you `select`ing your data?

Comment: Select state_abbreviation from names_table group by state_abbreviation

Comment: You probably don't even need an index on this table since its so small.

Comment: 51? You've missed a few. See [Official USPS Abbreviations](https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm).

Comment: try [analyze table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) and see if it doesnt change to 51

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43660

Comment: Thanks everybody...A few replies:  Assaf, Yes, I do need the index; the table has millions of rows.  I'm not sure why you thought it was a small table.   Catcal; 51 is correct for my purposes, 50 states plus DC.  We don't have military abbreviations or US territories.  Chris, thanks - your analyze table suggestion did the job and all the indexes changed a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chris, the analyze table seemed to do the trick.  I can't say I understand it any better why this was happening, but that seemed to clear it up.